# why a protect route is blocking all the next routes in the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, backend

a protect route is blocking another routes in seperate files and not allowing users to perform certain actions and can’t figure out why mentioning that i am using nodejs and express...
please help

I debugged everything and when I removed the protect route which is route.use(auth.isAdmin)
in userRoute i got access to the next routes in the file pubRoute but of course I had another protect route for certain actions only admin can access and it blocked the routes in the next seperate file which is commentRoute

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.